# How to use this.executeAction("someAction") in function based Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, fluxible

I've a class based component in which I'm calling the redux store through a action.

```
class App extends Component {
//Calling Constructor & setting State & other things
this.executeAction("someAction");
}
```

I want to know what would be the alternate for this in functional Component.
P.s:- I'm not sure if it is some library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useDipatch` hook from `react-redux`

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
function App() {
    //Calling Constructor & setting State & other things
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    dispatch("someAction")
}
```